# Can't load Fiddler because Fiddler Port in Use

Tags: port, fiddler

Windows pop-up message as belows:

```
Unable to bind to port [Localhost:8888]. ErrorCode: 10048.

This is usually due to another service running on this port. Run NETSTAT -A at a command prompt.
```

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Try asking on superuser.com ?

Comment: Did you run `netstat -a`, as instructed? What was the result?

Answer (score 6):

`Tools` menu -> `Fiddler Options` -> `Connections` tab -> `Fiddler listens on port`

There you can change the port that Fiddler uses.

Comment: I couldn't edit this field, so I ran fiddler from the command line and specified the port: Fiddler.exe -port:0 (zero for random in this example)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation while working with my local web server. 
After this error message Fiddler didn't monitor any of my connections from the browser.

I did changed port on 8085 in 
Fiddler Options -> Connections tab -> Fiddler listens on port:
but I also checked check box "Act as system proxy on startup", and after restart it started to work as usual.

I hope it helps.